# Add JS array values to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
var arr = [3,0,1,0,0];
```

and multiple divs.

```
<div class="fb0"></div>
<div class="fb1"></div>
<div class="fb2"></div>
<div class="fb3"></div>
<div class="fb4"></div>
```

and more.

How to add values from an array alternately by numbers in an array to div numbers by classes.

```
<div class="fb0">3</div>
<div class="fb4">0</div>
<div class="fb2">1</div>
<div class="fb3">0</div>
<div class="fb1">0</div>
```

Comment: You can use .each() method.

jQuery('[class^=fb]').each(function(idx){
  if(arr.length >= idx) // check if the array length is grater/equal to the current index.
    jQuery(this).text(arr[idx]);
});

Comment: I don't get why in the second block of HTML the `div` elements have been reordered into different positions? Is there any logic to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through all the div. Inside event handler function use the index to take the item from the array and set the text of the current element:

```js
var arr = [3,0,1,0,0];

$('[class^=fb]').each(function(idx){
  if(arr.length >= idx) // check if the array length is grater/equal to the current index.
    $(this).text(arr[idx]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fb0"></div>
<div class="fb1"></div>
<div class="fb2"></div>
<div class="fb3"></div>
<div class="fb4"></div>
```

JavaScript solution with [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var arr = [3,0,1,0,0];
var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[class^=fb]'));
elements.forEach(function(div, idx){
  if(arr.length >= idx) // check if the array length is grater/equal to the current index.
    div.textContent = arr[idx];
});
```

```html
<div class="fb0"></div>
<div class="fb1"></div>
<div class="fb2"></div>
<div class="fb3"></div>
<div class="fb4"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the div's and than using forEach you can add the values to each div accordingly.

```js
function update(){
  let arr = [3,0,1,0,0];
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=fb]')
  divs.forEach((e,i)=>{
    e.innerHTML = arr[i]
  })

}
```

```html
<div class="fb0"></div>
<div class="fb1"></div>
<div class="fb2"></div>
<div class="fb3"></div>
<div class="fb4"></div>
<button onClick=update()>Click me to see output</button>
```